# SQLite Local Date(Shamsi) comparison

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, date, comparison

I've stored fields with the local date(Shamsi) in my SQLite DB. I want to get a list of DB where its date is between date_1 and date_2. It works when using a const value as below:
`db!.rawQuery(("SELECT * FROM $tblVisit WHERE $colVisitDate BETWEEN '1401-10-01' AND '1401-12-29' ")`

but I like to use variables from function input instead of const value. How can I write something like follows:

```
String? date_1, String? date_2

db!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tblVisit WHERE $colVisitDate BETWEEN $date_1  AND $date_2 ")
```

Now, the last statement returns no list but the first one works well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text/String values must be enclosed in single quotes so

```
db!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tblVisit WHERE $colVisitDate BETWEEN '$date_1'  AND '$date_2' ")
```

Otherwise the dates, as they only contain numerics and operators, are considered an expression so 1401-10-01 becomes 1390 and thus unusual results.

However, this is susceptible to SQL injection and thus it is considered better practice by the *SQL Injection Police* to use parameter binding. That is, code **`?`** placeholders instead of the values, e.g. `BETWEEN ? AND ?` and then use the `selectionArgs` parameter of [`rawQuery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) for the 2 date values (note that you cannot bind component names and keywords).

See [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))